# Global variable scope when importing modules

Tags: python, scope

I don't understand why i can't access the `df` variable when i separate the function to another file and import that file.
The `df` variable has been declared as a global variable.

It is not a problem once the `globalDf` is in the same file as the `print(df)`.
What is behind this how to i make sure that i can access global variables declared inside functions across my code?

### Doesn't work

##### file 1

```
import pandas as pd

def globalDf(msg):
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(msg, columns=['val1', 'val2'])
```

##### file2

```
from file2 import *

arr = [[100, 400]]

globalDf(arr)

print(df)
```

### Works

Putting the `globalDf` function in the same file as as the `print(df)`:

```
import pandas as pd

def globalDf(msg):
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(msg, columns=['val1', 'val2'])

arr = [[100, 400]]

globalDf(arr)

print(df)
```

Comment: At the time you did `from file2 import *`, the variable `df` *did not exist* - it is only created when you call `globalDf()`.  After that call, you could repeat the import, or do `from file2 import df`, to get it in your namespace - but a more normal solution would be for the function to `return` the value, that you could assign to a variable name of your choice.

Comment: Even if `df` had been set, the `from ... import *` would create a *new* `df` in the current global space unrelated to `file2.df`. Calling `globalDf` would only modify `file2.df`, not the new `df`.

Comment: i finally underrstand how it works thanks people!

Comment: Beside the point, but shouldn't `from file2` be `from file1`?

Answer (score 0):

> **Globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules.**

If you want to access a global variable from another module you need to this:

file2:

```
import pandas as pd

def globalDf(msg):
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(msg, columns=['val1', 'val2'])
```

and file1:

```
#file1
from file2 import *

import file2

arr = [[100, 400]]

globalDf(arr)

print(file2.df)
```

This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) is useful as well.